# PowerShell or script to make all lists and libraries unsearchable?

Tags: list, search, powershell, library

I realize I can do this at the site or site collection level (can't remember which).  However, I need every one turned off individually so that I can then go back and choose which libraries/lists are searchable.  Since I have a ton of lists and libraries, and most I do not want to appear in search results, it would be arduous to do this on a one-by-one basis.  Bad planning, I know......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 $site = Get-SPSite http://siteColl    
    $site | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL | ForEach-Object {   
        foreach ($list in $_.lists) 
        {                  
                    $list.NoCrawl = $true
                    $list.Update()
        }
    }

    $site.Dispose()
```